# TBODY attributes are lost when adding a list of TBODYs to a table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I use JS to add a list of TBODYs to a table but in the resulting HTML the attributes of each added tbody are missing

I need this structure for a Stimulus controller.

```
<html lang="it">
<body>
     <table>
        <tbody class="tbody" data-value="hello">
            <tr>
                <td>a row in 1st block</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tr class="last-block-element">
            <td>last element of 1st block</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="tbody" data-value="hello">
            <tr>
                <td>a row in 2nd block</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tr class="last-block-element">
            <td>last element of 2nd block</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<script>
    const tbody = document.querySelector('.tbody')
    const lastBlockElements = document.querySelectorAll('.last-block-element')
    const newBody = `<tbody class="tbody" data-value="new-body">
                        <tr>
                            <td>another row</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>`
    lastBlockElements.forEach(element => {
        element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', newBody);
    })
</script>
</html>
```

This is the result:
[the executed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvdcF.png)

Comment: Your expected output markup is invalid. You can't have both a `tbody` _and_ a set of `tr` elements as child elements of `table`. It's [either/or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Comment: Thank you @Andy. Now I can solve my problem wrapping the "free" <tr> in a <tbody> and using this as "last block element"

Answer (score 1):

Try this JS code:

```
const lastBlockElements = document.querySelectorAll(".last-block-element");
const newBody = (existRow) =>
  `<tbody class="tbody" data-value="new-body"> ${existRow} <tr> <td>another row</td> </tr> </tbody>`;

lastBlockElements.forEach((element) => {
  element.parentElement.outerHTML = newBody(element.outerHTML);
});
```